# Laravel 5.4 - categorias y subcategorias (no mostrar subcategorias que no estén publicadas)

Tags: laravel

Buenos días,

Tengo dos tablas: Marcas y bajos, y lo que quiero es hacer un listado que muestre las marcas que están publicadas, y a continuación los bajos que pertenecen a esa marca y qué estén publicados. Tengo los siguiente archivos

Modelo Bajo

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Bajo extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'bajo',
        'url',
        'id_marca',
        'mastil_material',
        'mastil_forma',
        'diapason_material',
        'trastes_numero',
        'cejilla_material',
        'cuerpo_material',
        'lugar_fabricacion',
        'publicado',
        'portada'
    ];

    public function marcas_de_bajo()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Marca','id_marca');
    }
}
```

Modelo Marca

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Marca extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'marca',
        'descripcion',
        'logo',
        'direccion_web',
        'publicado',
        'portada',
        'id_pais'
    ];

    public function bajos_de_marca()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Bajo', 'id_marca');
    }
}
```

Dentro de controlador_paginas tengo la consulta

```
public function listado_bajos()
{

    $marcas = Marca::with('bajos_de_marca')
        ->where('publicado',1)
        ->orderBy('marca','ASC')
        ->get();

    return view ('bajos.listado', compact('marcas'));
}
```

Y luego la vista donde carga el listado de resultados

```
@foreach($marcas as $marca)
    <p>{{ $marca->marca }}</p>

    @foreach($marca->bajos_de_marca as $bajo)
    <p>
        <a href="{{ route('bajos.mostrar' , $bajo->url ) }}">{{ $bajo -> bajo }}</a>
    </p>
    @endforeach

@endforeach
```

Me muestra los siguientes resultados:

ESP

- Steve Harris
- Precission Bass

Fodera

- TBR
- 1006J
- CV4

G&L

- SB-Black
- Coda 4 Pro

Gibson

- XJ-1T
- Jazz-Style 7
- Vanquish V49K
- G6199 Billy Bo
- Jupiter Thunderbird Bass
- Grainger 4

El problema es que si añado por ejemplo ->where('bajos.publicado',1), para que muestre los bajos que están publicados, dentro de controlador_paginas me salta un error del tipo

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'bajos.publicado' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `marcas` where `publicado` = 1 and `bajos`.`publicado` = 1 order by `marca` asc)
```

Answer (score 1):

Tambien se podria utilizar un join.

```
$marcas = Marca::join('bajo', function($join){
            $join->on("bajo.id_marca","=","marca.id_marca");
   })
    ->where('marca.publicado', '1')
    ->where('bajo.publicado', '1')
   ->get();
```

Otra solución rápida seria agregar una condición al método bajos_de_marca en el modelo Marca:

```
public function bajos_de_marca()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Bajo', 'id_marca')->where('publicado', 1);
}
```

Otra forma sencilla también seria aplicar el filtro o condición en el foreach de la vista.

Comment: Muchas gracias! Me ha funcionado así. Lo utilizaré a partir de ahora de esta forma

Answer (score 0):

Buenas para realizar una busqueda dentro de una relacion de un modelo necesitas utilizar el WhereHas, segun el error que has pegado, estas intentando buscar dentro de Marca un Bajo que tenga publicado a 1.

Seria algo como esto, para buscar las marcas con publicado a 1 y los Bajos con publicado a 1 dentro del modelo Marca:

```
$marcas = Marca::where('publicado', 1)->whereHas('bajos_de_marca', function ($query) {
    $query->where('publicado', 1);
})->get();
```

Te recomiendo que uses Tinker que viene integrado con Laravel, cuando tengo problemas con alguna consulta suele ayudarme mucho. Un saludo

Comment: Acabo de hacer una prueba y muestra los bajos que no están publicados, o sea, que no me está funcionando.

Comment: Es que en la vista no utilizo esa función.

Comment: lo acabo de ver si , sigue probando esa consulta q marcas te retorna. El whereHas tiene que funcionar.

Comment: Tiene que tener como foreign key en la tabla bajos el id_marca. Es que no lo tengo así

Comment: Prueba de nuevo con el codigo que lo he editado.

Comment: Al final me ha funcionado el código que ha puesto Bryan

Comment: Es otra manera :P